# Free monad sequence versus colimit over injections of ordered sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff, monads

Kelly describes a constructive procedure for building the algebraically free monad on a pointed endofunctor. Garner gives a concise summary, which I partially review here for convenience.

---

Let $V$ be a cocomplete category (feel free to make other strong assumptions about $V$ if I have omitted them) and $(S,\eta)$ a pointed endofunctor of $V$. Define $X_0=\mathrm{id}_V$, $X_1=S$, and $\sigma_0:SX_0\to X_1$ as the identity. Then assuming $\sigma_0,\ldots,\sigma_i$ and $X_0,\ldots,X_{i+1}$ are defined, define $X_{i+2}$ and $\sigma_{i+1}:SX_{i+1}\to X_{i+2}$ as the coequalizer of the following diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
SX_i @>\sigma_{i}>>X_{i+1}\\
@VS\eta X_iVV @V\eta X_{i+1}VV\\
SSX_i@>S\sigma_i>>SX_{i+1}
\end{CD}

Then putting $\{X_i\}$ together via the maps $X_{i}\xrightarrow{\eta X_i} SX_{i}\xrightarrow{\sigma_i} X_{i+1}$, the resulting diagram
$$
X_0\to X_1\to \cdots
$$
is the (finite part of the) *free monad sequence* for $(S,\eta)$. If we make what seems to be a fairly strong convergence assumption, then the colimit $X_\omega$ of the sequence is the (algebraically) free monad on $(S,\eta)$.

---

On the other hand, another thing one could thing to do is to consider $(S,\eta)$ as generating a semicosimplicial functor $S_*$ where $S_n= S^n$ and the coface maps are given by $S^i\eta S^j$. Then one could consider the colimit of the diagram made up by coface maps up to a certain point:

$$
S_0\to S_1\rightrightarrows S_2\to\cdots \to S_n
$$
Call this colimit $Y_n$.

Inductively it looks to me like $X_i\cong Y_i$ and so $X_\omega\cong Y_\omega$.

Here are my questions.

> 1. Is there something subtly (or not so subtly) wrong with this observation?
> 2. The presentation of $Y_n$ and $Y_\omega$ seems "more symmetric." Assuming the answer to question 1. is "no," is there a good reason to prefer the presentation of $X_n$ and $X_\omega$? Is this because things will go badly as soon as one needs to extend to infinite ordinals in the free monad sequence?
> 3. If the answer to question 1. is "no," is there a reference that uses the $Y_n$ presentation to build this sequence where I can see in detail whether there are secret assumptions I am suppressing?

*Richard Garner*, MR 2506256 [**Understanding the small object argument**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10485-008-9137-4), *Appl. Categ. Structures* **17** (2009), no. 3, 247--285.

*G. M. Kelly*, MR 589937 [**A unified treatment of transfinite constructions for free algebras, free monoids, colimits, associated sheaves, and so on**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0004972700006353), *Bull. Austral. Math. Soc.* **22** (1980), no. 1, 1--83.

Comment: Here's a variation on your construction: A pointed endofunctor $(S,\eta)$ generates a semicosimplicial object $S_\bullet$ in the category of endofunctors of $V$. (Still assuming that $V$ is cocomplete,) If $S$ commutes with colimits of semicosimplicial objects, then the colimit of $S_\bullet$ is in fact the algebraically-free monad on $(S,\eta)$. I think the reason that Kelly uses a different approach has to do with weakening the colimit-preservation assumption on $S$: since the semisimplex category is not filtered, only a limited range of functors commute with its colimits.

Comment: But for example, if you vary the setting, replacing endofunctors by objects in a monoidal closed category $V$ and composition of endofunctors by $\otimes$, the colimit of the semicosimplical object you get $I \to S \overset{\to}{\to} S \otimes S \dots$ will be the free monoid on $(S,\eta)$, because $\otimes$ preserves _all_ colimits in each variable. The colimit preservation condition is serious: it is needed in order to define multiplication.

Comment: thanks @tim-campion, this is exactly the kind of answer for #1/#2 that I was hoping for. Two questions: 1) in your first comment, how is the thing you describe a variation of (rather than exactly the same as) my construction? 2) Is there a handy reference?

Comment: As for (1), the only reason it's a variation is that I wasn't taking any colimits at the finite stages, just once and for all at the end.  As for (2), one issue with understanding Kelly is that he's trying to work in maximum generality. in the introduction to Kelly's paper he discusses the earlier work that he's unifying. It's possible that one of those references has a simpler construction. Tom Leinster's _Higher Operads, Higher Categories_ has a free monoid construction under different hypotheses in Appendix D. Maybe I'll write up the simple case in an answer.

Comment: Other sources for free monoid constructions include the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+monoid) (for the easy case) and a [note by Steve Lack](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.243.2569&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The note by Steve Lack takes a perspective, which apparently goes back to [Dubuc](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869374900957), building on work of [Barr](http://telegraphics.com.au/~toby/CoequalizersAndFreeTriples-Barr.pdf) which is similar to the one we were talking about here. The Lack paper is nice; it focuses on the finitary case.

Comment: I knew about the nlab and hadn't found it particularly helpful, but the Lack note is very clear and as you say directly in line with our discussion here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's talk about free monoid constructions in a monoidal category $(\mathcal{V}, \otimes, I)$. Free monad constructions are a special case, when we take $\mathcal{V}$ to be a monoidal category of endofunctors. There are at least two flavors: the free monoid on an object $X$, and the free monoid on a pointed object $I \to X$.

It's pretty easy to construct the free monoid functor $T: \mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{V}$ in typical monoidal categories -- just take $T: X \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty X^{\otimes n}$, or in the pointed case, $T: I \to X \mapsto \varinjlim_{n\to \infty} X^{\otimes n}$ using the map $I \to X$ to define semicosimplicial connecting maps. The issue is with defining multiplication. We want to say that $TX \otimes TX = \varinjlim_m X^{\otimes m} \otimes \varinjlim_n X^{\otimes n} = \varinjlim_{m,n}X^{\otimes m+n}$, and then define multiplication $\mu_X: T^2 X \to TX$ by the universal property of the colimit, setting $X^{m+n} \to T^2 X \overset{\mu_X}{\to} TX$ equal to $X^{m+n} \to TX$, where the unlabeled maps are the canonical colimit inclusions. If you think about this, you'll see it's the usual formula for multiplication in a free monoid. The diagrams all commute, so we can define this map $\mu_X$ with no problem.

The problem is that the domain of $\mu_X$ is $\varinjlim_{m,n} X^{\otimes m+n}$, and in order to identify this with $T^2 X$, we had to commute a colimit past $\otimes$ -- we needed the functor $TX \otimes(-): \mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{V}$ to commute with the colimit defining $TX$. This is fine if $\otimes$ is (right) closed, in which case $TX \otimes(-)$ commutes with *all* colimits, so these simple constructions work in the familiar cases of free monoids in categories like $\mathsf{Set},\mathsf{Ab}$, etc.

But right closedness is simply not true in a category of endofunctors $\mathcal{V} = [\mathcal{C},\mathcal{C}]$. The condition becomes slightly different in this setting -- if you start with $F$ and define $M(C) = \varinjlim_n F^n C$, you want to argue that $M^2(C) = \varinjlim_m F^m (\varinjlim_n F^n(C)) = \varinjlim_{m,n} F^{m+n}(C)$, for which it suffices for $F$ to commute with the colimits defining $M$. Unfortunately, this is not often the case, although I believe the semisimplex category is at least sifted, so if $F$ commutes with sifted colimits you might be in luck.

Otherwise I don't know a shortcut to reading Kelly. I think the trick to reading his paper on a first pass must be to keep in mind that you can take the factorization system he uses to be $(M,E)$ = (all maps, isos), and then "preserving $E$-tightness of a cocone" just means preserving a colimit. What I currently understand is that Kelly gives free constructions endofunctor -> pointed endofunctor -> well-pointed endofunctor -> monad. I'm currently most mystified by the middle one.

Comment: Great answer! Now I want to go back and try to read that Kelly paper again.

Comment: Those were exactly my sentiments about the question! So a big thanks to @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole for noticing this entrée into understanding what Kelly is doing! Also since writing this answer I've noticed that unlike the cosimplex category, the semisimplex category is _not_ sifted, so the condition of preserving its colimits is really quite stringent.

Comment: $m+n$ in this post should be $m \cdot n$.